# jQuery Tab with tab titles as links

Tags: jquery, tabs

I'm using the standard jquery tab functionality and i was wondering if there is any way to make some of the tab headers simply a links that will redirect the user to another pages.

I'm actually want that when you hover over the tab you will see: "http://www.mysite.com/mypage" , i.e, the href of the tab header will be a simple link.

please let me know if its doable.

Thanks

Comment: What have you done so far? Can you show us an example?

Comment: What do you have? What have you used? You're not a novice user anymore, you should know better.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can make links to other pages, not sure if that your question.   If you want the user to see the URL when they hover  make the `title` attribute of the link the url, and it will show as a tools tip.

ie:

```
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" title="http://www.stackoverflow.com">My Tab</a>
```

If you need help with the tabs themselves, thats too broad.  Try using [jQuery Tools](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tabs/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Straight from the jQuery UI website:

```
$('#example').tabs({
    select: function(event, ui) {
        var url = $.data(ui.tab, 'load.tabs');
        if( url ) {
            location.href = url;
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

When you set up your tabs, make the href attribute a hyperlink instead of using the "#tab" format.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/v2pKQ/2/